# Python weakref слабые ссылки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясните, пожалуйста, смысл слабых ссылок, и что происходит со слабыми ссылками, когда работает сборщик мусора?

Comment: Thanks  very much

Answer (score 2):

Они не увеличивают счетчик ссылок. Соответственно, объект на который есть такая ссылка, может быть уничтожен. Особо полезно это при организации кешей (например, чтобы не хранить в памяти огромную коллекцию картин).

С самими слабыми ссылками при работе счетчика мусора ничего не происходит, он уничтожает объекты (и сильные ссылки), а не слабые ссылки.

Вообще, масса статей на эту тему (часто пересказывающих друг друга).Вот, например, ссылка на статью самого основателя:-)
https://habr.com/ru/post/599411/